# Call C from Prolog

Tags: c, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I've built the dll using this command:

> > "C:\Program Files (x86)\swipl\bin\swipl-ld.exe" -o test new.cpp pro.pl

It created a test.dll.

Prolog code.

```
:- module('test.dll', [ say_hello/1 ]).
:- use_module(library(shlib)). 
:- initialization load_foreign_library(foreign('test.dll')).
```

And this is the C code.

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <SWI-Prolog.h>

    static foreign_t
    pl_say_hello(term_t to)
    { char *a;

      if ( PL_get_atom_chars(to, &a) )
      { printf("DLL TEST ");

    PL_succeed;
      }

      PL_fail;
    }

    install_t
    install_mylib()
    { PL_register_foreign("say_hello", 1, pl_say_hello, 0);
    }
```

And now I call C from Prolog:

> ERROR: Exported procedure test.dll:say_hello/1 is not defined

What's wrong? Please, tell me.

Comment: Sounds like it is looking for a function names `install`...

Comment: Is that your entire C module? According to the SWI documentation, it says *Make sure that one of the files provides a global function install_mylib() that initialises the module using calls to PL_register_foreign().* See [Calling C From Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220539/call-c-from-prolog).

Comment: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=calling-prolog-from-c
go through this link..it should answer your question..